# How to write docstring for url parameters

Tags: python, flask, url-parameters, docstring

We have a flask api, and I am writing the docstrings for the classes.
Each get method has url parameters in the form of url/?key=value, like for instance /?format=csv, When writing the docstrings, what is the best/recommended way of documenting them?
My first idea was to put them in the method docstring, but pycharm and pylint complain as they are not actual arguments of the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to documenting APIs there are various approaches. One widely adopted documentation solution is Swagger.

To document Flask project with Swagger there is a library called 
[flasgger](https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger)

With this library, you can put API documentation directly in Docstrings: [source](http://brunorocha.org/python/flask/flasgger-api-playground-with-flask-and-swagger-ui.html)

```
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flasgger import Swagger

app = Flask(__name__)
Swagger(app)

@app.route('/api/<string:language>/', methods=['GET'])
def index(language):
    """
    This is the language awesomeness API
    Call this api passing a language name and get back its features
    ---
    tags:
      - Awesomeness Language API
    parameters:
      - name: language
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        description: The language name
      - name: size
        in: query
        type: integer
        description: size of awesomeness
    responses:
      500:
        description: Error The language is not awesome!
      200:
        description: A language with its awesomeness
        schema:
          id: awesome
          properties:
            language:
              type: string
              description: The language name
              default: Lua
            features:
              type: array
              description: The awesomeness list
              items:
                type: string
              default: ["perfect", "simple", "lovely"]

    """

    language = language.lower().strip()
    features = [
        "awesome", "great", "dynamic", 
        "simple", "powerful", "amazing", 
        "perfect", "beauty", "lovely"
    ]
    size = int(request.args.get('size', 1))
    if language in ['php', 'vb', 'visualbasic', 'actionscript']:
        return "An error occurred, invalid language for awesomeness", 500
    return jsonify(
        language=language,
        features=random.sample(features, size)
    )


app.run(debug=True)
```

If you do not want to document your parameters in doc strings you can also specify them in separate YML files. That is also described [here](http://brunorocha.org/python/flask/flasgger-api-playground-with-flask-and-swagger-ui.html)